# Visual Studio: Checklist to debug/fix LNK1104 error

Tags: visual-studio, linker

Every time I get a [LNK1104](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx) `"cannot open file 'filename'"` error  in Visual Studio, it takes time to find the cause, often a careless mistake.
What is the list of steps to follow to be sure to track this error down?